# How do i check if the tags within a parent are equal and then check if the tag is empty or not?

Tags: xslt

Consider the below example:

```
<parent>
<child1/>
<child1_old/>
<child2/>
<child2_old/>
</parent>
```

I need to check if each child has an _old tag. How do i do it?
And if the _old tag is a Null value.
Should i use for each of parent inside another For each of Parent?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Especially this part: "*And if the _old tag is a Null value.*" Post a more detailed example, including the expected output of each case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct template matching instead of `for-each`. Consider the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), '_old')][.='']">
        <test>Successful match</test>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```